# Run SQL command in loop until reach time condition

Tags: t-sql, while-loop

I need to solve following problem (in TSQL):

```
DECLARE 
    ,@CurrentTime AS DATETIME = GETDATE()
    ,@KillTime AS DATETIME
    ,@ProcessToKill AS VARCHAR(100)
    ,@KillProcessCommand AS VARCHAR(100)
SET @KillTime = comming from concrete select
SET @ProcessToKill = process ID comming from concrete select
SET @KillProcessCommand = kill command
```

e.g.:
CurrentTime = 2022-06-01 16:00:00.830 ; KillTime = 2022-06-01 15:55:00.000

My loop should go in circle, until CurrentTime >= KillTime - if fulfilled, then kill the process, otherwise repeat each 5 minutes.

Could someone help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to run a loop to wait for a time, you can just use the [`WAITFOR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/waitfor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) command, e.g.

```
PRINT 'Time start: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 8);
DECLARE @Time VARCHAR(8) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(SECOND, 5, GETDATE()), 8);

WAITFOR TIME @Time;

PRINT 'Time End: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 8);
```

**[Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3df1286bfd1ecb41212dada56b2505b8)**

If you don't want to wait until a certain time, and want to keep periodically checking a condition, then you can use a `WHILE` loop with `WAITFOR DELAY` within it then run your kill command at the end (if the process still exists):

```
DECLARE @ProcessToKill INT = @@SPID,
        @KillTime DATETIME = DATEADD(MINUTE, 10, GETDATE());

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE spid = @ProcessToKill) AND @KillTime > GETDATE()
BEGIN
    WAITFOR DELAY '05:00';
END
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE spid = @ProcessToKill)
BEGIN
    --Kill your procesws
END
```

Comment: thank you. this is good. maybe additional question. what if i don't want to literally wait until this time, but I want to check if my date condition is fulfilled, e.g. each 5 mins. (reason: my process which I'm checking with datetime condition can finish earlier then defined end time and then I'm waisting my resources). thanks